# How to order posts by meta_value and title

Tags: posts, wp-query, order, plugins

How do you order products in WooCommerce so that products are random, but at the same time featured products show first?

Here is my code:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'showposts' => $show_posts,
    'meta_key' => '_featured',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'desc',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'paged' => $paged
);


$all_products = new WP_Query( $args );
```

I have tried adding `rand` after `meta_value`, but it just randomizes products (in other words the featured ones don't display first).

Thanks in advance